# Show Nav Bar on Button Click - Doesn't Close Afterwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

So I've set up a new navigation on my website so that it is now hidden as an icon and displays when it is clicked. Once clicked again it is *supposed* to hide the menu again, however, it does not.

**Example of Menu Closed:**

[image: Closed Menu]

**Example of Menu Opened:**

[image: Opened Menu]

Clicking the three bars icon opens the four menu buttons you see in the second example, but then when I try to click the button to close the menu, it does nothing... even though it is supposed too. Any help on fixing this would be greatly appreciated.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="menu-button">
        <a href="#main_nav" id="access_nav"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    </div>

    <nav id="main_nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Navigation Section
---------------------------------------------------------------------- */

.menu-button {
    padding-top:25px;
    padding-left:30px;
    float:left;
}

.menu-button a {
    color:#eee;
}

.menu-button a:hover {
    color:#940002;
}

#main_nav {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

#main_nav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}

#main_nav li {
    display:inline;
    margin:0 10px;
}

#main_nav a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
}


.with_nav #main_nav {
    display: block;
}


#main_nav:target {
    display: block;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<!-- JavaScript
================================================== -->
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/430ad8b17b.js"></script>
<script>
var nav = document.getElementById('access_nav'),
    body = document.body;

nav.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    body.className = body.className? '' : 'with_nav';
    e.preventDefault();
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue isn't your JavaScript, it's your CSS. When `#main_nav` shows up, it's covering up the icon, so the icon is no longer clickable. You're clicking on `#main_nav`, not the icon. You can easily tell this because the hand mouse pointer your get on hover turns into a regular mouse pointer when the nav shows up.

In your CSS, the fix that makes the most sense is to remove the `padding-left` on `#main_nav` and use `left` instead, since you're already absolutely positioning it anyway.

```
#main_nav {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  /*padding-left: 40px;*/
  left: 60px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Working snippet:

```js
var nav = document.getElementById('access_nav'),
  body = document.body;

nav.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  body.className = body.className ? '' : 'with_nav';
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.menu-button {
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  float: left;
}

.menu-button a {
  color: #000;
}

.menu-button a:hover {
  color: #940002;
}

#main_nav {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  /*padding-left: 40px;*/
  left: 60px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#main_nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#main_nav li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

#main_nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.with_nav #main_nav {
  display: block;
}

#main_nav:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-button">
  <a href="#main_nav" id="access_nav"><img class="fa fa-bars" src="http://placehold.it/25x25"></a>
</div>

<nav id="main_nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Worked a treat! Appreciate the help !

Answer (score 0):

body.className? '' : 'with_nav';
maybe create a class instead of setting it to no class. im not sure if this clears its css properties....